# Is there a way to send messages typed with my own classes to an Akka remote actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

Is there a way to send messages typed with my own classes to a remote actor?
For instance I would like to be able to received in my remote actor a message like this:

```
case myClass: MyClass => doSomething()
```

But I get an error `local class incompatible` because the `serialVersionUID` are different.

The sole way to send a message of type MyClass that I have found is to serialize it in Json. But I have to serialize/deserialize it, and more problematic, I don't have a clean way to receive two kinds of typed messages...

So is there a way to send strongly typed messages to a remote actor? If not, what is the workaround?

Comment: It looks like your have 2 different versions in class paths of your actors. Check classpaths and define explicit value of  `serialVersionUUID`

Comment: "By strongly typed I mean typed with my own classes" - you probably ought to rephrase, because that's not what that means to anyone else

Comment: @ChrisMartin What would be the correct name for this?

Comment: I don't think it's a real thing. There's no such distinction on the JVM between "your classes" and "other classes".

Comment: As to the literal question: [they are working on it](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/typed.html), but that is still experimental.

Comment: Ok, but if I send a message with a String or a Int or a usual type I don't get any error, so I thought there was a difference on the JVM.

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko How do I check the classpaths and how do I define an explicit value of the serialVersionUUID?

Comment: @phg so the only way to do what I want is to use the experimental Akka Typed module?

Comment: No, you seem to have a different problem, related to your setup (and the versions of you class files). The comment was just what I would answer solely to the question in your title, as "strongly typed" usually means something different than your usage of it (e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Static_type-checking)).

Comment: Ok so the problem probably comes from Play! because the remote actors telling to each others are created inside two different Play! applications... Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You most certainly can!

When sending objects over the network, they must be turned into bytes on one end, and turned back into objects on the other end. This is called 'Serialization'.

In Akka the serialization mechanism used for messages travelling from one actor system to another is highly configurable: you shouldn't do it in your own actors, but leave it up to Akka's serialization infrastructure (and configure that to your liking).

By default akka uses the built-in 'Java serialization'. This mostly works, but as you noticed is pretty picky about having the exact same class on both sides of the connection. Also, it is not particularly fast. You should have seen a warning in the logging:

> Using the default Java serializer for class [{}] which is not
>   recommended because of performance implications. Use another
>   serializer or disable this warning using the setting
>   akka.actor.warn-about-java-serializer-usage

To fix your problem you can either:

- Keep using Java serialization, and at least fixate the `serialVersionUID` as described in Vitaliy's answer.
- Switch to another serialization mechanism such as Protobuf.

If you don't care too much about performance and don't expect to do 'rolling upgrades' (where you might need to convert between different versions of the same message), Java serialization is certainly the easiest. It's important to be aware of its limitations, though.

Further documentation on how to configure akka's serialization mechanisms can be found at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/serialization.html#serialization-scala

Answer (score 1):

From `Serializable` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> it is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly
>   declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID
>   computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary
>   depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in
>   unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization.

So, you should define `serialVersionUID` in your message classes like this:

```
@SerialVersionUID(42L)
class Message extends Serializable
```